# Can't connect to remote database table

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, .net-3.5

I have a desktop application which access a database in a lan environment which works find.  However, the database has now been moved to a remote hosting company and I can access the database like so using query analyser:

```
select * from server_name.database_name.dbo.table_name
```

In the old lan environment, I was able to access the database like so using query analyser:

```
select * from database_name.dbo.table_name
```

The problem is, that my desktop application gives the following error when I change the sql within it to include the server_name:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot find the object "table_name" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Anyone know why this is happening.  How do I go about giving the desktop app rights to the database, when it's using the same connection string as I use to connect to the database when using query analyser?

Comment: Add the remote server as a linked server then access it ... `SELECT * FROM LINKEDSERVERNAME..DATABASENAME.TABLENAME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem is not in the access rights, but in the incorrect call to table.
More chances that you just can't find the table you're trying to acces.

You should update your connection string to match changes related to database moving on remote server